# Not able to connect to the wired network.  Wireless connects fine.

Tags: networking, network-adapter, wired-networking

I am not able to connect to the wired LAN from hostel rooms. I am able to connect to the wifi connection.

I have checked that the NIC is working properly by connecting two computers with a crossover cable, and that is working properly.  I am facing the same problem from both windows and Linux, so that seems to confirm that there is not a virus problem.

Can anybody help me in identifying issue ??

Comment: Please re-word your question. What specifically are you trying to do? "I am not able to connect college LAN from hostel rooms." doesn't specify what you're trying to accomplish. Are you tring to connect into a college LAN? Are you trying to connect two LAN's together? If you're able to connect via WiFi, what specifically isn't working?

Comment: We have LAN connection in hostel room and wifi connection in college buildings. I am able to connect wifi but for LAN I can't connect..

Comment: What happens when you try? How far do you get? What's the first step that gives you trouble? Does the link light come on? Do you get assigned an IP address?

Comment: Have you paid for/asked for LAN access - many places will not 'patch' in your room until you ask/pay for access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to connect before via wired? Or has it never been possible? 
If the case is the later maybe you can contact your IT dept, as HaydnWVN mentioned, could be they will only whitelist your mac address after you apply for a connection.